# force sceensaver lock when hibernating on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, passwords, hibernate, screensaver

I've poked around in settings but haven't found the right one.

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/19386/how-can-i-make-ubuntu-not-lock-my-screen-when-i-close-my-laptop) poses almost the opposite problem.

I have my power management set to hibernate when I hit the power button. When it resumes from hibernate, the screen is not locked.

I have my screensaver set to *not* lock because I want to be able to avoid the password e.g. after reopening the lid when I haven't hibernated.

But I'd like to have a password set automatically when resuming from hibernate in case the laptop is stolen so that at least there's a slightly higher degree of difficulty to steal data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a program called `gconf-editor` to directly change various settings. It's kind of like Windows' registry editor. Press Alt+F2 to get the run dialog, and type `gconf-editor` and hit enter. Browse the tree to `/apps/gnome-power-manager/lock/` and poke around at the settings there until you get the behavior you want. You'll probably want to *uncheck* `use_screensaver_settings`.

Comment: +1 for the helpful tips. Unfortunately those settings don't seem to work.

Comment: They seem to have started working. (I had rebooted at least once before my previous comment, not sure what changed.) Thanks for your help.